# Hide div when User is scrolling on mobile / display div when the scroll stops

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I didn't find the exact answer to my problem that I will explain here :

I want to hide a fixed element when the user is scrolling. When the scroll action is finished, the div is displayed again. This does not take into account a trigger on the height (with a scrollTop for example) but simply on the scroll action itself.

This behaviour is for mobile use.

I made a quick code snippet for trying something :

thanks a lot

```js
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function() { 
    document.getElementById('paragraph').classList.toggle('test');
  });
```

```css
p {
  position:fixed;
  background:wheat;
  
}

div {
  height:2000px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
}
```

```html
<div>
<p id="paragraph">Has to be hidden on scroll</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When scroll function is triggered we will hide the div and then we have to check whether the scrolling is stopped for this we can use setTimeout function

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {

  $("#paragraph").fadeOut(); //hide div

  document.getElementById("paragraph").classList.toggle("test");

  clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
    $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
     $("#paragraph").fadeIn(); //unhide div after few milliseconds
   }, 550));

});
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/musama125/pen/NWXZwpR)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution i have used in the past:

https://codepen.io/webdevjones/pen/GRybONR

```
//initialize scrollTimer
let scrollTimer = -1;

//add event listner
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => { 
  //get the element(s) to hide while scrolling
  const elem = document.getElementById('paragraph')
  //hide the element(s), you could also just use opacity 
  //or visibility depending on your use case
  elem.style.display = 'none'
  
  //while we are scrolling, restart the timer
  if (scrollTimer != -1){
        clearTimeout(scrollTimer)
  }
  
  //if the timer isnt cleared, we run the function to 
  //display the element(s) again
  scrollTimer = window.setTimeout(() => {
      elem.style.display = 'block'
  }, 1); 
  //running the function 1ms after scroll stop, 
  //you could increase this number if neccesary
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).